# What kind of helicopter hats can I wear?

Tags: swing-copters

I was playing Swing Copters and won a silver helicopter hat, hooray!

[image]

I was wondering:

1. Are there any other hats to unlock?
2. What do they look like?

Screenshots would be appreciated!

Comment: I have unlocked a red hat and a weird pink suit, I don't know if there are more

Answer (score -1):

I have got 81 and after the red and pink there is yellow hat sunglasses a jury and a purple ccharacter

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Since you already unlocked those, can you post a screenshot?